# How to reconnect redis connection?

Tags: node.js

I have simple example:

```
var redis = require('redis'),
client = redis.createClient();

var test = function() {
    client.brpop('log', 0, function(err, reply) {
        if (err != null ) {
            console.log(err);
        }    else {
            .... parse log string ....
        }
        test();
    });
}

test();
```

How to reconnect redis connection after restart redis server ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The Redis client automatically reconnects. Just make sure you handle the `"error"` event from the client. As per [the example](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#usage-example):

```
var redis = require('redis');
client = redis.createClient();
client.on('error', function(err){ 
  console.error('Redis error:', err); 
});
```

Otherwise, [this code](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/blob/master/index.js#L140-143) is where the process begins.

```
this.emit("error", new Error(message));
// "error" events get turned into exceptions if they aren't listened for.  If the user handled this error
// then we should try to reconnect.
this.connection_gone("error");
```

Next, the [.connection_gone()](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/blob/master/index.js#L365) method runs on the client.

Notice that you can also listen to a `"reconnecting"` event to be notified when this happens.